# Page freezes after js function called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I got checkbox. If it's checked then we set input fields enable else they disabled. So when I load page first time it works okay. But after it's just freezes. In Chrome console seems that there are nothing appears.

Why could it be?

So heres the element

```
<label  class="switch span2">
        <input id="p_switcher" name="action" type="checkbox" class="switch-input"/>
        <span class="switch-label" data-on="New Project" data-off="Open Project"></span>
        <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
</label>
```

fileds looks like that (as example)

```
<input type="text" name="ProjectName" placeholder="Project Name" id="textProjectName" disabled/>
```

heres the JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // disable not usable fileds 
            var handlers = function () {
                $('input#p_switcher').change(function () {
                    //setting the atributes 
                    var setAttr = function (fieldName, value) {
                        $('[name=' + fieldName + ']').attr('disabled', value);
                        w2ui.form.fields.filter(function (x) { return x.name == fieldName; })[0].required = !value;
                    }                
                    if ($('input#p_switcher').prop("checked", true)) {
                     //   setAttr('projectId', true);
                        setAttr('ProjectName', false);
                        setAttr('CompanyName', false);
                        setAttr('FieldOperator', false);
                        setAttr('FieldName', false);
                        setAttr('Unit', false);
                    } else {
                     //   setAttr('projectId', false);
                        setAttr('ProjectName', true);
                        setAttr('CompanyName', true);
                        setAttr('FieldOperator', true);
                        setAttr('FieldName', true);
                        setAttr('Unit', true);
                    }

                    w2ui.form.refresh();
                    handlers();
                });
            }

            setTimeout(handlers, 500);   
       });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the `handlers()` function again from within the `change` event?

Comment: Yes, and why every 500ms? once should suffice

Comment: oh, well, guys thing like that was in one of examples which I got (like a demo to show how MVC & ORM stuff works, actually I am pretty new for that). But there was value from `list` not the `checkox`

Comment: And it was worksing fine actually. But yeah I see the recursion now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('input#p_switcher').prop("checked", true)) {
```

On this line you are essentially triggering the `.change` event again.

I think you mean:

```
if($('input#p_switcher').prop("checked")) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is it… You are calling handler from within handler, without timeout…

```
$(function () {
        // disable not usable fileds 
        /*
         * shortened
         */

                //recursion, no timeout
                handlers();
            });
        }

        setTimeout(handlers, 500);   
   });
```

Comment: `handlers()` will not cause any recursion, rather it will just bind an additional `change` handler

Comment: well, actually this caused one problem - it was working slower and slower every click so, thank you too, +1